# How to Call PHP Function in a Class from HTML Button Click

Tags: php, html, button, click

I am a rookie PHP developer.

I have a PHP web project with an HTML page that contains an <kbd>Add</kbd> button. The name of the page is `Awards.html`. Elsewhere I have created a PHP class, `Awards.php` which contains a function.

The source code of my files is given as follows:

#### Awards.html

```
<div class="divparent">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn" data-bind="click: closeModal">Exit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-title">
        <h1 id="headerid">Awards</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="hdnValueCurrentAwardSoid" type="hidden" value="null" />
        <div class="divleft">

            <input id="txtName" maxlength="80" type="text" class="water newpost1" placeholder="Award Name" tabindex="1" />        

            <section class="ThumbnailContainer">
                <img id="imgThumbnail" class="imgThumbnail" />
                <img src="http://localhost/rockontechnologies/Images/GreenRibbon.png" id="pictureribbon" class="pictureribbon" />
                <input type="text" contenteditable="false" readonly id="transformtext" />
            </section>

            <textarea id="txtdescription" placeholder="Description" class="water newpost1" rows="4" tabindex="2"></textarea>    

            <div class="ui-widget">
                <input id="txtIssueOrg" maxlength="50" type="text" placeholder="Issue Organization" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "divbottom">
        <div id="divAddAward">
            <button class="btn" onclick="">Add</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Awards.php

```
    <?php

    class Awards
    {
        function clickFunction()
        {
            //Function that needs to be executed!
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that on the click event of the <kbd>Add</kbd> button, I need to call the `clickFunction()` of the `Awards.php` file. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: PHP is serverside and HTML client side. So you can't really call the `clickFunction` in your class directly. You will need an Ajax call or submit your form to another PHP page that calls the `clickFucntion`

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Can you please provide me the AJAX source code on how to achieve this and the location where I need to place this code?

Comment: You should be able to extract enough information from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like that

```
<button class="btn" onclick="onrequest();">Add</button>

function onrequest() {
      $.post( 
          'example.php'
       ).success(function(resp){
            json = $.parseJSON(resp);
            alert(json);
       });
}
```

and in example.php call your function

```
$class = new Awards();
$method =  $class->clickFunction();
echo json_encode($method);
```

and in your clickFunction();

```
clickFunction(){
 $array = array(
   'status'  => '1'
 );    
 return $array; 
}
```

Comment: Will this code work in my Awards page as it is an HTML file? Also, how will it exactly route the call to the clickFunction() function in the Awards.php class file?

Comment: It doesn't work when I change the file format from HTML to PHP because that page is part of a single-page application framework.

Comment: download and add jquery-1.10.2.js from jquery.com

Comment: write function in script tag like this <script>  function onrequest(){ code } </script>

Comment: Is it necessary for the button to be surrounded by the <form> tag?

Comment: no if your calling ajax request u don't need this but if you submitting a form you have to add <form> tag

Comment: I have removed the <form> tag but it's still not working. Basically the program control is not entering the .success property. I tested it by inserting alert('Test'); code over there. When I insert the same alert before the $.post() function, it does get executed successfully which means that it enters the onrequest() function but not inside the .success property.

Comment: Okay I checked that and I saw that it is not able to find the index.php file. Any statement on how to include files in JavaScript. Sorry for sounding like a noob but I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Okay I got it working now. The example.php file was not getting loaded. So I added the $("#divAddAward").load('example.php'); code and the code got executed. Thank you very much for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

first of you have to a instance of class which is like that

```
$class = new Awards();
```

then if you want to onclick event you should make a javascript code but how to get the function you can do like this

```
<?php echo $class->clickFunction(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Can you please provide me the complete source code on how to achieve this and the location where I need to place this code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't call a class directly from HTML in PHP you have to call it through HTTP by loading a page.

Hence, use a AJAX call to call Awards.php. Eg. with JQuery it could look like this `$.get("Awards.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})`

In your php-file you should also call your class something like this `<?php echo $class->clickFunction(); ?>`