# Access PHP method from HTML onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I'm trying to develop a webpage (`menu.php`) which has a `<div>` when clicked accesses "one" of the many methods in the `stock-c.php`. The code I have developed as follows:

#### menu.php

```
<?php 
require_once '../control/stock-c.php';
?>
<html>
<body>
    <div onclick="<?php $obj=new StockController(); $obj->checkAccessRights();?>">  //I know this is a wrong implementation
       //some code here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### stock-c.php

```
class StockController{
    public function checkAccessRights(){
        //some code here
    }
    public function getPID(){
        //some code here
    }
}
```

I know `menu.php` file's `onclick` event is a wrong implementation.

Since there will be other situations that I will need to call other methods (like `getPID()`) in other PHP web pages, I'm not sure if using jQuery to create an AJAX call on the `onclick` event in `menu.php` to access an "altered" `stock-c.php` file such as:

```
class StockController{
    $obj=new StockController();
    $obj->checkAccessRights();

    public function checkAccessRights(){
        //some code here
    }
    public function getPID(){
        //some code here
    }
}
```

which was suggested in [How to Call PHP Function in a Class from HTML Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304054/how-to-call-php-function-in-a-class-from-html-button-click) would work as this breaks my ability to access the other function. I just am not sure what alternatives I have. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't get your question, really :(

Comment: Hmm...sorry. Basically I want to alter the solution posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304054/how-to-call-php-function-in-a-class-from-html-button-click# by "Agha Umair Ahmed" so that I can specify to access any method in the Awards.php page (stock-c.php in my situation).

Comment: You will have to do an ajax call to a php script that calls your method, which is what that other question is suggesting.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php Have you seen this, you could combine it with a get request. @user3889963

Comment: not possible. PHP runs on the server. You can **NOT** invoke php code by clicking on something in the client's browser. At most you can do an ajax request/form submission will will end up running PHP code on the server.

Comment: @Adam Forbis...Are you suggesting I use ajax to send a post variable to stock-c.php so that depending on the value sent it will invoke the necessary method? Or were you suggesting something even more better that that??

Comment: @user3889963 that is pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks...:-) I think you are the only one who understood my question. Thanks for your help man...:-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to call different methods in a script would be to use PHP's [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). This would allow calling the script with a get or post request and use the input to select which function to call.

From php.net:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
        $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name(); // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

For security reasons it may be a good idea to put something like a switch statement or other way of limiting input to keep a user from invoking arbitrary functions.